# Assert middleware is attached to express endpoint in unit test

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Is there a way that I can assert the middleware is actually attached to the route in my unit test below?

The server ..

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express(); 
var server = http.createServer(app);
var PORT = 5000;
var myModule = require('myModule');
var handler = require('handler');

var myMiddleware = myModule.doStuff(server);

app.use('/', myMiddleware);

app.route('/')
  .get(function(req, res) {
    handler.respond(req, res);
  });

if (!module.parent) {
  server.listen(PORT, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      logger.error(err);
      return;
    }
  });
}

module.exports = app;
```

`handler.js` contains ..

```
var handler = {
  respond: function(req, res) {
    res.sendStatus(200);
  }
};

module.exports = handler;
```

`myModule.doStuff` is implemented using ..

```
function doStuff(server) {

  const SERVER = server;

  return function (req, res, next) {
    if (server.connections === 2) {
      res.send({
        message: 'Overloaded'
      });
    } else {
      next();
    }
  }
}
```

I test the routes are setup using ..

```
describe('/', function() {
  it('should test endpoint', function(done) {
    sandbox.stub(handler, 'respond', function(request, response) {
      response.send('called');
    });
    request(app).get('/')
      .expect('called')
      .end(done);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can change your middleware to something like this:

```
function doStuff(server) {

  const SERVER = server;

  return function (req, res, next) {
    req.doStuffRun = true;
    if (server.connections === 2) {
      res.send({
        message: 'Overloaded'
      });
    } else {
      next();
    }
  }
}
```

Then you will be able to test for `req.doStuffRun` in your callbacks.

But here it doesn't seem that it is called because you are not running the actual request but you are calling the `handler` which does not contain the middleware.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way that I can assert the middleware is actually attached
>   to the route in my unit test?

Well that question actually has two sides to it.

### Testing that Express.js works as its supposed to

I would personally consider it a waste of time to test Express.js. It already has it's own [test suite](https://github.com/expressjs/express/tree/master/test) and it has been around for ages and therefore you should be able to trust that `app.use()` works as it is supposed to.

### Testing that you are passing the expected middleware to `app.use()`

This is more relevant and you can lay the groundwork for being able to perform tests by structuring your code this way:

```
var myMiddleware = {
    m1: {
        path: 'somePath',
        callback: 'someCallback'
    },
    m2: {
        path: 'anotherPath',
        callback: 'anotherCallback'
    }
}

function mountMiddleware () {}
    for (var middleware in myMiddleware) {
        app.use(middleware.path, middleware.callback);
    }
}
```

Now you can perform unit testing on the contents of `myMiddleware` and the workings of `mountMiddleware()` and thereby assert that all your middleware is correctly passed to `app.use()` (which you expect to work).